# How to hammer in tight place

Tags: wood, kitchens

I have the back of my kitchen sink base unit that has popped out, is made of thin plywood. Now it's raised outside if it's groove and I need to hit it with a rubber mallet to push it down into the slot. My problem is hitting it from the top is not possible as the space is quite tight, I can only raised the hammer about an inch.

Is there such a thing like a elongated 'Z-shape' metal bar that one side of the 'Z' I can hang onto the plywood and then the elongated neck brings the other lip of the 'Z-shape' down where I can comfortably hit it? What would this piece of tool be called if it did exist? Or is there another way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not that I've come across. Sure, you can find bars shaped like that, or make your own, but they're not readily available in tool stores.

Your best bet is probably to try and pry the panel down rather than hitting it with a mallet. Use a flat bar or large screwdriver or other tool along with a block of wood to protect the edge of the panel. Exactly how you do it will depend on the particulars of your situation.

Update: [Mazura](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/23295/mazura) reminded me about a flooring installer's best friend, the [Z-bar](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Roberts-Pro-Pull-Bar-for-Laminate-and-Wood-Floors-10-18-8/100390108). Might do the trick, but at a cost for one little task.

Comment: A flat bar isn't what the op is asking for here, and I don't think it would do the job.